# Store value in service-worker in Angular

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I had created a service-worker and make it get to register.
I used below code in some js file

```
self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    console.log('installing');
})
self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
    console.log('activating', event);
})
```

Can i store a variable value in angular.
Like I want to store a value of 'x' in the cache by using a service worker.
How can I do that?

Comment: Check [Live Data in the Service Worker](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/live-data-in-the-service-worker). It describes recommendations for storing different kinds of data in a PWA.

Answer (score 4):

**Use IndexedDb for this.**

You can store the value in IndexedDb inside of the Service Worker and then access it inside of the Angular app. The [localForage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) library provides a nice to user wrapper around IndexedDb, you can use this library in both your Service Worker and inside of Angular.